# Start shell with screen

Tags: shell, gnu-screen, bash

I'm tying to accomplish a very simple task. start my shell with screen. 
In my .profile file. I have this

```
if [ -f /bin/bash ];
then
        echo "Switch to bash."
        exec bash
```

switches to bash.

but if I just include "screen" inside my .bashrc, I get in an infinite loop of screen prompt, because bash runs screen recursively.

If I include. "exec bash -c screen" terminal never gets going?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider not using the profile script when you run screen:

```
exec screen bash --noprofile
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i completely understand what you mean? if I put the following inside .bashrc it will not work.

Comment: @kmassada It won't work with .bashrc since .bashrc is always executed for every interactive instance of bash. That would if it's in .profile. However you could use --norc instead if you're placing it in .bashrc.

Comment: you got it!! it works. So if I understand correctly. this runs screen which runs bash?? but the noprofile part? why is it key?

Comment: Simply to prevent bash from reading .profile again when it's already been called through screen.